# Can we read counters of third part application?

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm trying to figure out with observability in dot .net applications. One item of that is Event counters.

We are able to read them with dotnet-counters tool if we want to read them outside the app or we can use `EventListerer` class if we want to read counters within our app.

Can we create our own app which will be read counters of third part app? dotnet-counters is somehow doing this but I didn't find any information how can you doing the same in your .net app.

Comment: What kind of third part app you are using?

Comment: There was an idea to create a tool like dotnet-counters but with custom features. Third part apps I meant apps which are running on .NET core CLR. Or in other words the apps which dotnet-counters tool is able to read from.